# Child page without parent's template/view

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have some states something like this:

```
stateHelperProvider.setNestedState({
    name: "root",
    children: [
        {
            name: "public",
            authenticate: false,
            children: [
                {
                    name: "login",
                    url: "/",
                    title: "Login",
                    views: {
                        "main@": {
                            controller: "LoginController",
                            templateUrl: "/views/login.html"
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I need the login page to use a blank template (as little as possible), instead of injecting into `main`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not move login to totally separate route ?

Comment: Because that `root`... route has some resolve functions that I don't want duplicated. I could create a parent of the `root` route that contained everything except the templates and make login a child of that, but I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: Yes there is - make login on separate path.

Comment: Well, I'll just do that then. Thanks! Want to make that an answer or will I just delete my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move login component to separate route.